# (C++) How to have stdout update in real time without affecting stdin

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to make a simple chat program in the Linux terminal. For simplicity, the "users" are just multiple instances of the terminal on a single machine. However, I don't know how to implement certain features that are crucial to the operation of the program:

My issue is partly about **updating stdout:** I know how to use `std::ofstream("filename.txt", std::ios_base::app)` to append to a file, but I don't know how to get the program to detect when someone sent a message. It would be impractical to reprint the entire file containing the messages once the file is hundreds of lines long.

I also want to be able to scroll up and see the chat history. This is normally available in basically any terminal program, but if I have to use things like ANSI escape sequences or `std::system("clear")`, I'm not sure if that would still be possible.

How can I implement a way of detecting when the file has been added to? I'm assuming something like `tail` is part of the solution, but I need to be able to do what `tail` does while **not affecting stdin:** The key part I'm having trouble with, I want to be able to receive messages and have them display on the screen, while I'm still typing, and nothing on the screen breaks.

A possible solution I was thinking of, though I can't figure out how exactly to implement it, is to change the keyboard mode (I once did this when I learned how to accept input of a password as ******* etc. in a terminal program).

The `->` line marks the one being typed on, and it should have the user's name on it so that way I can tell which instance of the terminal it is. It might be best to just use a CLA when starting the program so I can give each instance a username.

How can I implement a way of updating the chat history while other users are typing, instead of just when the user presses Enter to move forward through the program?

My goal is to support **at least 4 terminal instances ("users") at once.**

Here, Alice started typing, then while typing, receives Bob's message, and can still be typing:

```
<bob> hi









alice -> Hi Bob, how ar
```

I was thinking the process would look something like this:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    //CLA check, get username, declarations, ...
    while (true) {
        updateChatHistory();
        checkIfUserPressedAKeyToTypeSomething();
        if (pressedEnter) {
            send(username, message);
        }
        //sleep for 20? milliseconds
    }
}
```

Edit: forgot to mention, that for simplicity (unless there is a better way to go about this), each terminal instance will just take turns appending to a common file like `chat.txt`.

Comment: I think you are looking for a library like `ncurses`.

Comment: C++ is just too hard to be learned by thinking up a program and figuring out how to write it. I estimate this requires about 3-5 years of C++ experience. This kind of a program requires using of operating system specific APIs, libraries, and/or multithreading. Are you familiar with these subjects?

Comment: Have you considered writing a GUI based application instead? With support of a framework (wxWidgets, Qt, FLTK, ...) this can end up much easier for you, as you'd have separate areas for displaying messages and writing them.

Comment: you do not keep your original post intact. I got confused in the very beginning of your quesiton because you talk about some file, and only in the very end the mystery is explained. You can [edit] and rewrite your question as much as you like, no need to add "Edit" and similar. If some piece of information is missing in the first paragraph better add it there rather than in a footnote.

Comment: The *correct* way to implement this is to make the 2 instances communicate directly with each other, such as with sockets or other IPC mechanism, not using files (unless you want to archive the messages). Then you can run the communication channel asynchronously so it can display messages onscreen in real-time as they arrive. And, you can scale the app to work on multiple devices over a LAN network or the internet.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have done extremely basic multithreading before, but that's about it.

Comment: @Aconcagua I could, but I have never written a GUI application. Which of those frameworks has the easiest learning curve? I want to understand all the basics for it first (that's why I'm not concerning myself with QoL right now).

Comment: [FLTK](https://www.fltk.org/) or [nana](http://nanapro.org/en-us/) gave me the impression to be pretty easy, [Qt](https://www.qt.io/product/framework) or [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) less in this respect, but appear more powerful to me. For the first few steps the former two should be fine, though. Maybe try out both and chose the one you feel more comfortable with.